# Почему MATCH ... AGAINST находит поля, в которых используется стоповое слово?

Tags: mysql, index, match

***Есть таблица classics, которая содержит 5 столбцов:

autor, title, category, year, isbn***


Для столбцов autor и title задан индекс fulltext. Я выполняю поиск с помощью команды

```
SELECT autor, title 
FROM classics 
WHERE MATCH(autor, title) AGAINST('and');
```

Почему-то вместо Empty set выдается результат поиска. Но ведь слово "and" является стоповым словом и оно должно игнорироваться при поиске. Причем если искать по слову "of", "is", к примеру, которые также являются стоповыми, будет выдано Empty set (названия со словами "of" и "is" существуют). Почему так?

Comment: *Но ведь слово "and" является стоповым словом* Да? А вы проверьте список...

Comment: @Akina где его найти?

Comment: @Akina видимо у меня в книге ошибка. Т.к. в книге есть список стоповых слов и в нем присутствует слово "and".

Comment: *в книге есть список стоповых слов и в нем присутствует слово "and"* Наверное, в книге про MyISAM рассказывают.

Comment: @Akina, нет про InnoDB

Comment: Ну в общем это ошибка в книге.

Comment: См. [Full-Text Stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And не является стоповым словом.